# Is there a way how to interpolate on pandas Resampler object directly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with irregular sampling frequency, therefore I would like to resample it and interpolate.

Lets say I have following data:

```py
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(["2021-01-01 00:01:35", "2021-01-01 00:05:01", "2021-01-01 00:08:42"])
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]}, index=idx)
#                      a
# 2021-01-01 00:01:35  1
# 2021-01-01 00:05:01  2
# 2021-01-01 00:08:42  3
```

And I would like to get result similar to this one (interpolation using "index" method):

```
                            a
2021-01-01 00:02:00  1.121359
2021-01-01 00:03:00  1.412621
2021-01-01 00:04:00  1.703883
2021-01-01 00:05:00  1.995146
2021-01-01 00:06:00  2.266968
2021-01-01 00:07:00  2.538462
2021-01-01 00:08:00  2.809955
```

For that, I thought that something like `df.resample("T").interpolate(method="index")` could work but this does not work, I would need to put there some aggregation function, e.g. `df.resample("T").mean().interpolate(method="index")` but it does not result in a wanted solution.

I could do some workaround like this:

```py
df_res = pd.concat([df, df.resample("T").asfreq()]).sort_index()
df_res = df_res[~df_res.index.duplicated()]
df_res = df_res.interpolate(method="index").dropna()
df_res
#                             a
# 2021-01-01 00:01:35  1.000000
# 2021-01-01 00:02:00  1.121359
# 2021-01-01 00:03:00  1.412621
# 2021-01-01 00:04:00  1.703883
# 2021-01-01 00:05:00  1.995146
# 2021-01-01 00:05:01  2.000000
# 2021-01-01 00:06:00  2.266968
# 2021-01-01 00:07:00  2.538462
# 2021-01-01 00:08:00  2.809955
# 2021-01-01 00:08:42  3.000000
```

And then remove the original 3 indexes or keep everything based on my preferences. But I'm wondering whether there is a better solution that could work directly by combining `resample` and `interpolate` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other ways to do this, but the base value of the original data is in seconds, so upsampling in seconds is the way to go. There is an interpolation method for resampling, so we will use that. This will result in a complemented data frame of 1 second units, and we will filter that data frame by seconds.

**df.resamle('S').interpolate()**

```
df.resample('S').interpolate().head()

                          a
2021-01-01 00:01:35     1.000000
2021-01-01 00:01:36     1.004854
2021-01-01 00:01:37     1.009709
2021-01-01 00:01:38     1.014563
2021-01-01 00:01:39     1.019417
```

**query**

```
df.resample('S').interpolate().query('index.dt.second == 0')

                          a
2021-01-01 00:02:00     1.121359
2021-01-01 00:03:00     1.412621
2021-01-01 00:04:00     1.703883
2021-01-01 00:05:00     1.995146
2021-01-01 00:06:00     2.266968
2021-01-01 00:07:00     2.538462
2021-01-01 00:08:00     2.809955
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I didn't think about this solution! Do you have any insights in the performance? By comparison on such small dataframe it's already 3 times slower, and I'm bit afraid that resampling to seconds and interpolation can cause some issue when you have really big dataframes..

Comment: This is a 3-step process, resample, interpolate, and extract, so it may have an impact on the number of cases. However, I think it is possible to break down these three steps and consider other methods. For example, you can use `numpy.interp`. I'm answering because the question said it could be done directly.